# What does "RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'" do?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Can somebody explain to me why this line is required and what this line is doing?

```
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
```

The full docker file lookes like this and in every templanete it can be found.

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD docker-example-service-1.0.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
EXPOSE 8080
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-Dapp.port=${app.port}", "-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: All `touch` does is update when the file was last accessed; and if it doesn't exist - it creates it. This is just being run in `sh` shell the `-c` flag just takes the next string as the command to run.

Answer (score 1):

touch command will update the timestamp to file, directory.

So that you can keep track of files when it's get created and updated.

RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'

when you invoke docker build, above command will update timestamp to app.jar.

For complete details of touch command refer below link
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utouch.htm

Answer (score -1):

> `touch` is a standard Unix command-line interface program which is used to update the access date and or modification date of a file or directory. [...] Touch can also be useful for quickly creating files for programs or scripts that require a file with a specific name to exist for successful operation of the program, but do not require the file to have any specific content.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix))

In your case it's most likely that the `touch` command is used to ensure that the file exists.